# Create hard link if possible, else use symlink

Tags: shell-script, symlink, hard-link, ln

I am trying to write a shell script to create link for file from my `dotfiles` repo to my home folder.

I want to use hard link if possible because it cannot be broken when moving it to somewhere in the same filesystem with `HOME`.

But if I clone the `dotfiles` to another filesystem, I have to use symlink instead.

---

So, how to create hard link for file if possible, else use symlink in shell script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ln source target 2>/dev/null || ln -s source target 2>/dev/null || exit 1
```

or, slightly more "interactively" (chattier),

```
if ! ln source target 2>/dev/null; then
    echo 'failed to create hard link, trying symbolic link instead' >&2
    if ! ln -s source target 2>/dev/null; then
        echo 'that failed too, bailing out' >&2
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

Remove the redirections to `/dev/null` to see the error messages displayed by `ln` (if any).